# xmodmap fails to clear any modifier

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm trying to remap my right Windows/Super/Meta/Command key to behave the same as my left Alt key (instead of what it's doing now which I believe is acting as "Super").  I've read a bunch of articles about using xmodmap to do this, but anything I do to try to change the modifiers fails, even for very simple operations:

```
> xmodmap -e "clear mod4"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  8
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

Output is the same for mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, or mod5, with capitol or lowercase "m"

I'm on a pretty clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Here's the output for xmodmap -pm, in case that's helpful:

```
> xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Caps_Lock (0x42),  Control_L (0x85),  Control_R (0x86)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x25),  Super_R (0x69),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, why is your command prompt `>`? It is normally '$`

Comment: Haha, that's not actually my real command prompt, I just wrote it that way for simplicity.  :P My actual command prompt is customized with a lot of information that is irrelevant to this question

Comment: I did `xmodmap -e 'clear mod4'` on my clean installed 20.04 worked. The error information described on [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/135200/xmodmap-fails-to-remap-modifier-keys) and you need `xev` to find the keycode of your RightWin key. You don't have to edit `mod4` in my thoughts.